# Are there three past continuous tenses in Spanish? When can I use Pretérito imperfecto / imperfecto progresivo / indefinido progresivo?

Tags: tiempos-verbales, pretérito, preguntas-canónicas

> This is a [canonical question](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2505/1674) / Esta es una [pregunta canónica](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2505/1674)

Are there three different past continuous tenses?

When I tried to learn the past continuous, I came across three different tenses that are used to express it.

1. **Pretérito imperfecto**
   which consists of **the root of the verb +** the endings **aba/abas/abamos/abais/aban**

   Example: los pájaros cantaban <sub>the birds were singing</sub>
2. **Imperfecto progresivo**
   which consists of **the subject + Verb estar (in El Pretérito Imperfecto) + Present Participle**

   Example: Él estaba trabajando a las siete <sub>He was working at seven o’clock</sub>
3. **Indefinido progresivo**
   which consists of **Estar [in El Pretérito Indefinido + gerund [-ando/-iendo]**

   Example: Ayer estuvimos bailando toda la noche <sub>Yesterday we were dancing all night</sub>

Can you explain to me when to use each of them and what is the difference?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a very complex topic!

First, comparing *imperfecto* and *indefinido* comes down to the difference between unfinished (that's the technical meaning of "imperfect") actions and completed actions or events.

*Pretérito imperfecto*, or "imperfect," refers to past events that were not finished in the context; these can be either habitual actions or single instances. For example:

> *Los pájaros cantaban.*

This means "The birds sang (habitually)" or "The birds were singing (at the time the speaker was there)".

*Imperfecto progresivo*, or "progressive imperfect," also refers to past unfinished events, but what's different is that here the actions were not habitual (except in some specific cases).

> *Él estaba trabajando a las siete.*

This means "He was working at seven" in a context where the speaker, for example, has seen the man working at seven and then left without seeing him stop working. This sentence *could* work with the simple imperfect too; but the progressive expression emphasizes the continuity or ongoing nature of the work.

*Indefinido progresivo*, or "progressive preterit," has a misleading name; it refers to past events that were finished (in the context of the meaning the speaker wants to convey). The progressive part means that something happened for a while -- and then stopped.

> *Ayer estuvimos bailando toda la noche.*

This means, "Yesterday we were dancing all night (and then stopped)." You cannot use the imperfect here because the qualifier *toda la noche* would make it nonsensical; because it was "all night" (i.e., the whole night), the meaning includes the idea of an end, a stopping.

If you're writing about something that was happening while something else happened as well, you use the imperfect (either simple or progressive):

> *Ayer estábamos bailando [*or* bailábamos] cuando comenzó a llover.* "Yesterday we were dancing when/as it started raining."

If the action went on for a while and then stopped (i.e. the speaker perceives that it stopped), you use the progressive preterit:

> *Él estuvo trabajando en su oficina hasta las ocho.* "He was working in his office until 8 o'clock."

If the event is habitual or customary, you use the simple imperfect:

> *Los pájaros cantaban todas las mañanas.* "The birds sang [*or* would sing] every morning."